# Repairing corrupt Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V VM using the host of an exact same OS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, disaster-recovery, system-restore

There's a Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials machine which had an SSD failure. It hosts a Hyper-V VM of exactly the same type OS. The system never got to the state that it wouldn't boot, but we were experiencing surprise restarts every other day.

(I managed to completely recover the host OS by first doing an `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` to fix the packages which can provide opportunity to fix the system itself later. That was done with an `sfc /SCANNOW`. That worked beautifully!)

Now I would like to restore the VM too, which can *almost* boot. The boot procedure starts and it almost reaches the login dialog but it returns back to the repair page.

I don't have any recovery DVDs. What I'd need is to restore the system files to a state where I could boot up, then I could perform additional recovery like I did for the host OS as well.

I don't know how to accomplish this though. The system restore menu doesn't accept the installation DVD as a source to restore the OSs state. Since the host OS and the VM's OS is exactly the same, is it possible to utilize the host and produce a recovery media what I can use to restore the VM?

Or is there any other way to restore it? Please advise!

---

At the Advanced Repair Options I could get to the Command Prompt as an Administrator, I ran `Repair-Volume –driveletter c –scan` (http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/repairing-corrupt-file-systems-vms-repair-volume/). It didn't find any logical errors. I can mount the `vhdx`, but cannot boot into it.

Comment: So, I'm just saying that we ended up with a fresh install on a new system. SSD failures can be even rougher than spinning HDDs